# ASP.NET - How to get and set MasterPage attribute in page code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page that uses a MasterPage. I have a `public` `bool` attribute in the MasterPage called `ShowChangePassword`. I want to set this to true or false in the page that uses this MasterPage.

I have the following code, but I can't set the attribute:

```
 var masterPage = this.Master;
 masterPage.ShowChangePassword = false;
```

What code do I need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a typed reference to your master page class. Put something like that in your content page:

```
<%@ Page  masterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"%>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>
```

Then you can do:

```
 this.Master.ShowChangePassword = false;
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work - the masterpage doesn't have the <%@ Page directive. Did you mean to put both server tags in the masterpage? Why would you reference the masterPageFile in the masterpage>

Comment: @aspdotnetuser: you must put the MasterType tag in the ContentPage you want to reference the master page in.